# Flutter Firebase only let certain data be shown on list view builder

Tags: flutter, google-places-api

I am trying to only display certain data from a collection. In my example, I only want to show data in the list where the collection in name on firebase is equal to the name of the widget. I am unable to solve this problem

```
 Expanded(
                            child: Container(
                            child: FutureBuilder(
                                future: getPosts(),
                                builder: (_,snapshot){
                                  if(snapshot.data["name"]== widget.info.name){
                                    return  ListView.builder(
                                        itemCount:
                                        x,
                                        itemBuilder: (_,index){
                                          return ListTile(
                                            title: Text(snapshot.data[index].data["name"]),
                                          );
                                        });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Expanded(
    child: Container(
            child: FutureBuilder(
               future: getPosts(),
                    builder: (_,snapshot){
                    return  ListView.builder(
                              itemCount:
                                snapshot.data,
                                 itemBuilder: (_,index){
                                 if(snapshot.data["name"]== widget.info.name){
                     return ListTile(
                                  title:Text(snapshot.data[index].data["name"]),
                                      );
                      }else{
                          return Container();
                        }
                 })}))
         );
```

Answer (score 0):

A better option will be to pass the widget name in the `getPosts()` function you defined and update the firebase query to do the filtering. This way it be much faster as firebase does the require indexing and will do the filtering in `O(len(filtered_elements))` rather than current time complexity of `O(len(all_elements))`.